# Prefix index length impact for VARCHAR?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a `VARCHAR(255)` primary field field in an `InnoDB` database table. I only store values of length 32 bytes in it (32 ASCII characters). My primary key has a prefix length of 767 bytes. Clearly, this longer prefix length than I need. Does this have any performance impact?

Answer (score 2):

If it is always 32 ascii bytes, then say `CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET ascii`.

There are subtle reasons for not making the field bigger than necessary.  They mostly involve how temporary tables are generated in complex SELECTs.  Most importantly, the tmp table is `MEMORY` and turns `VARCHAR(255)` into `CHAR(255)` of the given charset.  If that is utf8, then you are unnecessarily using 755-32 extra bytes for each row in the tmp table.  This can lead to slowdowns.

"32" smells like hex for something?  UNHEX(...) and put it into `BINARY(16)` to make the PK even smaller.

Every secondary key (in InnoDB) implicitly includes a copy of the PK.  Making the PK bigger than necessary can impact disk space.